# Criar filtro dos eventos FullCalendar

Tags: dropdown, fullcalendar

Bom dia,
Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um filtro em uma dropdown que irá me retornar determinados eventos.
Um exemplo é esse: http://www.mikesmithdev.com/demo-fullcalendar-with-event-filtering/, porém com uma dropdown.
Dei uma olhada em alguns materiais, mas nada que pudesse me ajudar.
Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Tive uma dúvida igual a sua. Resolvi da seguinte maneira: sempre que o select é alterado, você pega o valor do option e utiliza esse valor para filtrar de todos os eventos que você buscou no ajax. Um exemplo seria:

```
$('#seleciona').change(function(){
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents');//remove os eventos anteriores
var idEspacoFisico=$('#seleciona option:selected').val();//Pega o id do option
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:'eventos/getEventos.json', //Pega todos os eventos
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,value){//Para cada valor do data, compara se o campo é igual ao filtro selecionado. Se for igual, renderiza.
            if(value.espacoFisico==idEspacoFisico){
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', value, true);
            }
        })
    }
});
});
});
```